# On Cauchy's Theorem (Proof)

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand the Cauchy Theorem from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) resource. I don't understand why (in 1st paragraph of the proof 1), "If p does not divide |H|, then it divides the order [G:H]". Would someone please explain it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: $p$ divides $|G|$ and $|G| = |H||G:H|$.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - Thank you!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Sorry, and why "If p divides |Z|, then Z contains an element of order p" in the second paragraph? Thank you.

Comment: Because it has been proven for abelian groups in the preceding paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this theorem;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)